# Can electricity pass through a flat battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries, electrochemistry

[image]Let’s say there are 4 batteries in series in a circuit connected to a bulb. One of the battery is flat. Can the bulb still light up?
I’m so confused now.

Comment: You won't get a meaningful answer if you can't give a more complete description of how the four batteries and the bulb are connected to one another. A diagram would be helpful. Also, it sounds like maybe not all four of the batteries are in the same condition? A little more description there would be helpful too.

Comment: This depends on what type of battery (meaning it is a question about engineering and off-topic here). For disposable batteries, internal resistance rises when it is flat and the bulb will not light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A battery (flat or not) is still a conductor and the circuit will remain complete. Its just that when the battery runs out, it wont be able to provide any extra voltage to the circuit. The bulb will still glow but the brightness will change (depending on if the batteries were in series or parallel configuration).

Comment: Also the battery will be charging now(even for non-rechargable batteries) as its voltage is less than the voltage supplied so the voltage supplied is equal to the voltage across the circuit and the battery. Typically you can model a battery as a circuit with a pure voltage source and a resistor. in this case the voltage source is zero

Comment: @ChemEng, re, "Also, the battery will be charging now..." That depends on how the batteries are connected.  If the batteries are connected in series (as is often done to obtain higher voltage,) then the other batteries will force a "discharge" current through the "flat" battery which, in the case of disposable "alkaline" cells, quite likely will cause the cell to rupture a seal, and leak corrosive juice (sodium hydroxide) inside your device.

Comment: yes if the plus is connected to the plus and the minus to the minus it will charge.